# Could you force meiosis in a cell that normally uses mitosis

Tags: dna-repair

I've read in the red queen something that suggests the DNA repair mechanisms are better in meiosis than they are in mitosis.
I was wondering if occasionally we could force some of our cells that use mitosis to use meiosis so as to clean up mistakes in our DNA.

Comment: It is not clear from your question if you understand the basics of mitosis and meiosis, especially the differences of outcomes of the two processes. Your question will have higher chance of being answered if you explicitly state what effort you have made to answer it yourself.

Comment: How would meiosis "clean up mistakes" in DNA?

Comment: @forest I would assume he is talking about gene conversion during meiosis and the [hypothesis/theory stating that crossing-over has evolved from a DNA repair mechanism.](https://www.intechopen.com/books/dna-repair/meiosis-as-an-evolutionary-adaptation-for-dna-repair)

Comment: it isn't going to help somatic cells to undergo meiosis, because at the end they would be haploid and not really capable of doing good somatic cell stuff... ie. if you were heterozygous for something that was a autosomal recessive disease ... half of the cells would end up with it... also if you were male (human) half of your cells would have a Y chromosome and half would have an X... in general in higher animals the gametophyte generation doesn't do a lot of living on its own.

Comment: @BagiM, yes I was sort of referring to the hypothesis you refer to. I was just reading "the red queen" and saw reference to the idea that germ cells had a better DNA repair mechanism that regular cells during meiosis and was wondering there might be some way to get somatic cells to occasionally use a better firm of DNA repair. I realize the haploid problem Grady mentioned. I'm not tried to get somatic cells to use meiosis exactly. Was just wondering if we could somehow encourage cells to us a better DNA repair mechanism. I am a physicist. I have cancer and am interested improved DNA repair.

Comment: @chemong In normal body cells there already is [Homology directed repair](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_directed_repair). If I remember correctly it is active in G2 phase where sister chromatids can serve as a template for reparation. The gene conversion would not do much good in multicellular organism because it would introduce genetic diversity of individual cells (in some cells allele A gets converted to B, in others B to A). Genetic diversity is a base of natural selection and I fear the whole thing would kickstart cancer instead of preventing it.